# Add "x / n completed today" on review queue page

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Small little QOL suggestion here.

In the review page, I think it would be nice to have a UI element to show how many reviews you've done for that queue today, rather than having to navigate to the stats page for that specific type of review.

Might look a little something like this (apologies for crappy mockup)

[image]

Perhaps we could even add icons for which badges you have for those queues? Of course, it shouldn't be too cluttered.

Maybe I'm just overthinking this and it's completely unnecessary, but there are a number of times when I've thought to myself that something like this could be useful.

Comment: Maybe on the review page itself, too.

Comment: Related: [Let me know how many reviews I've done inside the queue.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250580/let-me-know-how-many-reviews-ive-done-inside-the-queue)

Comment: I just remember at the beginning of the day what my score in each queue is ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified @rene's userscript in this [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250580/let-me-know-how-many-reviews-ive-done-inside-the-queue), to work on the review page.

This is what it looks like.

[image]

Tested in Chrome with Tampermonkey. It should work fairly well, but let me know if it acts up.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Review Queue Stats
// @namespace    http://stackoverflow.com/users/2278598/andrew-brooke
// @version      0.1
// @description  UI tweak to StackOverflow review queue page
// @author       Andrew Brooke
// @match        http://stackoverflow.com/review
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function($, window) {

    $('.dashboard-item').each(function () {
        var url,
            progressHTML = $('<div class="dashboard-num-today"></div>')
        .html('...')
        .css('text-align','center')
        .css('color','#75845C')
        .css('padding-top','8px');

        url = $(this).find('.dashboard-activity-more').attr('href');

        $.get(url, function (data) {
            var html = $(data),
                td = html.find('td.review-stats-count-current-user:first');
            if(td.text() != "")
                progressHTML.html(td.text() + '/&nbsp;20');
            else
                progressHTML.html('');
        });

        $(this).find('.dashboard-count').append(progressHTML);

    });

}($ || unsafeWindow.$, window || unsafeWindow));
```